# Run a java class file from a webpage on the visitor computer?

Tags: java, browser, file-io, applet

I coded a Java program to read and modify a file on the computer.  The program is based only on 1 class.

At the moment who want to use it has to run it from terminal, I'm looking on how to insert it on a webpage and make it run on the visitor's computer.  It would be fine to have a file chooser (the user will want this modification).

I searched on internet and found Java applets, but I read that they aren't downloaded and executed locally so the program won't work.

How to provide a Java class file from a webpage, for use on the computer of the end-user?

Comment: ...or you need to ask those guys in that french company who hacked all browsers including chrome

Comment: no it's clean, it get a config file of a program and modify it. And it's ok that user is prompted to start java :)

Comment: I'm still learing java so I insert the absolute path to it, but yes it would be fine to have a file chooser

Comment: @AndrewThompson i know mate. just trying to refer all his needs :) http://360techreviews.com/2012/03/08/google-chrome-hacked-by-vupen/

Comment: @kommradHomer *just trying to refer all his needs"*  Have you ever considered using your powers ..for **good?** ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ..it would be fine to have a file chooser ..

In that case, there are basically the two options as I've outlined in comments throughout this question & the answers.  I'll collect them together here:

1. Digitally sign the applet, get the user to accept the digitally signed code when prompted (before the applet is loaded), then offer a `JFileChooser` to browse to the file.
2. If the user has a plugin 2 JRE (chase the links in the [JWS info. page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info) for more details), it is possible to deliver the applet to the user unprompted, then leverage the JNLP API to produce a file chooser.  The user will be prompted before the dialog appears, this time with a more specific warning.

### JWS

- For an example, see my applet based [GIF animation tool](http://pscode.org/gifanim/#applet) which uses the JNLP API when the user goes to load image frames or save the animated GIF.
- That applet is not open source (mostly because of my laziness in not wanting to revisit & tidy the code) but there is a much better [example of using the JNLP file services](http://pscode.org/jws/api.html#fs) that comes complete with source.

### Digital signatures

I don't have any great links about the process of digitally signing code, but note that the 'example of using the JNLP file services' listed above provides one set of signed Jars for 2 different security environments.  It also (hopefully obviously) demonstrates how to digitally sign code using Ant (it all happens by invoking the default task in the `build.xml`).

Comment: I'm going with the signed applets as I'm still new with java, but thank you very much for your complete reply :)

Comment: but with a solution like your gifanim user has to download a file and start it, it doesn't start "automatically"

Comment: <head-desk/>  **Any** code has to be downloaded before it can run and affect files on the user's computer!  The **download** happens automatically once the user clicks the link in their browser.  Did you try visiting the applet and clicking a few menu items - ***to see how it works?***  Cripes!  As an aside, if you check the 'top-ranked' providers of answers for either [applets](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/applet/topusers) or [JWS](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/topusers), it supports that I know 'a little' about both.

Comment: ok, but now I'm totally confused :S I think I will continue this "project" when I will be more familar with java, thank you for your help Andrew :)

Comment: *"I think I will continue this "project" when I will be more familar with java"*  That is the smartest thing I've heard so far on this thread ( that was not said by me ;).  That is a ***great*** idea.

Answer (score 3):

If you really want to download a Java program and run it locally, you should check out [Java Web Start](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/index-jsp-136112.html).

Briefly, it allows the user to download and run a Java program locally on their machine. It does clever stuff like identify if an updated version is available for download, and will run the cached version if that's the current version.

Here's a [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/webstart/).

Comment: Here's the SO [info. page on JWS](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info) which provides a good summary (in my biased opinion) & further links (including the one to that ..very obscure page at Oracle).  If you visited that first link to Oracle's description of JWS & had never heard of it, would that page would explain it?  It'd leave me scratching my head.  JWS is a great deployment technology that is dubiously named and poorly described by the supplier. :(

Comment: Happy to provide any help & tips I can, especially to the people who apparently help out on a regular basis.  :)

Answer (score 1):

Applets can modify files locally, *if* they are signed *and* the user allows them to.

Read up on signed applets.

Comment: "Applets can modify files locally, *if* they are signed" *..or* if they use the JNLP API.  (No digital signing needed, but also with prompts.)

Comment: I created a jar and self signed it, now when starting as applet it ask for full access to computer, so it should work but sadly no, I'm now looking where is my error :)

Comment: Ahh, the 'the squeaky wheel gets the oil'.  ;)  As to the problems you are facing with code signing.  It should work OK once signed and the user clicks OK.  It might be better to take that up on a separate question if you want to pursue that route.

Answer (score 0):

> I read that they aren't downloaded and excuted locally

Whereever you read that, it is 100% incorrect. Applets are downloaded into the browser and executed at the client host.